# Store large files in hadoop

Tags: java, hadoop, hbase, hadoop2

Need to create a api for storing millions of files. Currently using hbase to store images which size from 1-10Mb. Now need to store large set of files where I cant store directly in hbase, and storing it in haddop will increase load of Name node.

What are all the possible solutions available and it must be open source?

Comment: currently working on the same kind of problem: read this to start if you haven't already http://blog.cloudera.com/blog/2015/06/inside-apache-hbases-new-support-for-mobs/ .

Comment: Yes, but cloudera is not an open source right

Comment: it's not about cloudera, you can have that in hbase 2.0, or maybe look at hortonworks (I don't know if they worked on that however